# How to handle exceptions in a batch process

Tags: 8, batch-operations

I have some special configured content entities in my system which are protected in a pre-delete hook against entity deletion.
There is also a batch process (VBO - entity delete) where they can be selected before hand.

I want to handle gracefully the exception in a batch process which wasn't written by me (and cannot be touched). I tried to subscribe to the exception event and look for xmlHttpRequest which was all fine, but then I dunno what response to set back to stop the process, or log the exception within the batch process with the proper message. What I always get back is this, where the error message is what I put into the AjaxResponse body:

[image]

Any help appreciated find a more sophisticated solution to redirect from the batch processing in case of an exception.

Comment: You need to return an ajax response. But solving the problem how you can pick up the batch once you've thrown an exception seems to be far more complicated than a simple try/catch statement around the delete in the batch process, so that you can pick up the deletion process right away in the same batch request without bothering the user.

Comment: But this is what am currently doing: returning an ajax response and I also attached the image above what the result is. This is not working as you can see.

Comment: And I also wrote: it's a 3rd party code, I don't even have the chance to put try catch block anywhere. Please read carefully again.

Comment: You would need to return an Ajax response which pickups the batch process, not a 500 status code. I've read the question. I didn't try to answer. My comment was saying, look you could add a simple try/catch to the batch or you have the very difficult task how to pickup the batch again once you are thrown out.

Comment: I find this unbelievable that the batch API cannot take care of simple exceptions.

Comment: Is it this action you are using https://git.drupalcode.org/project/views_bulk_operations/blob/8.x-3.x/src/Plugin/Action/EntityDeleteAction.php? Why not write your own action wrapping a try/catch around $entity->delete?

Comment: This what I did in the end: create my own plugin, extend from VBO plugin, and then just pust entity->delete in try catch.
Thank you for your support!

Comment: Great, do you mind posting the plugin code as an answer?

Answer (score 3):

So in the end I took and overrode the plugin provided by the [VBO](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations).
This will put the exception message into the summary displayed with a `drupal_set_message` at the end of the batch process (VBO 3.0.0-alpha2).

```
namespace Drupal\my_module\Plugin\Action;

use Drupal\views_bulk_operations\Plugin\Action\EntityDeleteAction;

/**
 * Delete entity action with default confirmation form.
 *
 * @Action(
 *   id = "my_module_delete_entity",
 *   label = @Translation("MyModule Delete selected entities"),
 *   type = "",
 *   confirm = TRUE,
 * )
 */
class MyModuleEntityDeleteAction extends EntityDeleteAction {

  public function execute($entity = NULL) {
    try {
      $entity->delete();
      return $this->t('Delete entities');
    }
    catch (\Exception $e) {
      return $e->getMessage();
    }
  }

}
```